# I've got this error in my code CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings' to 'string' Tutorial

Tags: .net

```
public partial class dridviewinser_update_Delete : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connectstringweb = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydatabase"],ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindgridview();
    }

    private void bindgridview()
    {
        //this is property
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectstringweb);
        con.Open();
        string query = "gridview_select_bindgrid";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        grdviewdata.DataSource = dt;
        grdviewdata.DataBind();
        con.Close();
        bindgridview();
    }

    protected void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectstringweb);
        con.Open();
        string query = "dridview_insert";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("Insert Successfull!");
        con.Close();


    }
}
```

Comment: You have a stray comma.

Comment: As @SLaks says, after the ["database"] you need a point to reference the ConnectionString property

Comment: Now is working but I've got exception System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147023895
  Message=Exception_WasThrown
  InnerException:

Comment: Removed the extra closing brace in code snippet. Possibly it was namespace's closing brace which is not included in the source code.

Comment: I sitll get some exception An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: I still get some errors An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code @Slaks

Comment: Read the error message.

Comment: I've read but I still confuse I am a  beginner in programming.

Comment: Can you debug your code and pin point which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: if `btninsert_Click` method is throwing error then you might want to check all the parameters you are passing to `dridview_insert` stored procedure. Are there only two parameters or more?

Comment: I put two parameters and I got the exception in  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();.

Comment: I checked the code now is working thank you guys!

Comment: I checked the code now is working thank you guys! the only problem it doesn´t show in my browser the information I insert.